# How to use gcloud compute scp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-functions

I want to download this file

[image]

to my computer, but I don't understand the command

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse [INSTANCE_NAME]:[REMOTE_DIR] [LOCAL_DIR]
```

The instance is the name of my file??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp

`[INSTANCE_NAME]` refers to the name of the target instance that you are transferring files to. The following example is taken from the above reference.

> To copy a remote directory, `~/narnia`, from `example-instance`
>   to the `~/wardrobe` directory of your local host, run:

```
$ gcloud compute scp --recurse example-instance:~/narnia ~/wardrobe
```

**Edit:**

After looking a bit closer at your image, it looks like you're trying to copy files from Cloud Storage? If you're looking to copy files from a Cloud Storage bucket you will need to use the [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) cli tool. To copy a file from a directory you'll need to use the `gsutil cp` command.

See the following for more information and examples:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp